# Filter by product attribute terms in a WooCommerce WC_Product_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to create a loop for products using **[WC_Product_Query](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query)**.
Now I want to filter them by Product Attributes.
Using **WP Query** it is possible to do this, with **tax_query**.
But using WC_Product_Query it does not work.
(I do not want a `WP_Query`, because for products it is better to use `WC_Product_Query`)

```
<?php
$query = new WC_Product_Query(array(
    'limit' => 5,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',      
));

$products = $query->get_products();
$products = wc_products_array_orderby( $products, 'price', 'DESC' );

if (!empty($products)) :
    ?>
    <table>
    <?php
    foreach ($products as $product) :
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($product->get_id()); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($product->get_id()); ?></a></td>
            <td><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $product->get_id(), 'thumbnail' ); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $product->get_price(); ?></td>     
        </tr>
        <?php
    endforeach;
    ?> 
    </table>    
    <?php
endif;
```

Here's how to do it in WP Query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_color',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'red',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as in a `WP_Query`, you can use a `tax_query` in a `WC_Product_Query` like:

```
$query = new WC_Product_Query(array(
    'limit'     => 5,
    'orderby'   => 'date',
    'order'     => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'pa_color',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'red',
    ) ),
) );

$products = wc_products_array_orderby( $query->get_products(), 'price', 'DESC' );

if ( ! empty($products) ) : ?>
    <table><?php
    // Products loop
    foreach ($products as $product) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($product->get_id()); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($product->get_id()); ?></a></td>
            <td><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $product->get_id(), 'thumbnail' ); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $product->get_price(); ?></td>
        </tr><?php
    endforeach; ?>
    </table><?php
endif;
```

Tested and works since WooCommerce version 3.